# How to make chef check for RPM package and then install?

Tags: rpm, chef-infra

I am currently using chef to install the RPM JDK package but the problem is that it does it every single time even if the package is already downloaded and installed. I tried finding an option for checking before installing but there wasn't any. Is there a way to get around this such that I can skip packages that are already installed? Debian's package management skips already installed packages by default, but RPM package manager doesn't seem to do that.

```
[Tue, 23 Oct 2012 10:34:32 -0500] INFO: Processing remote_file[/var/chef/cache/jdk-1.6-u30-linux-amd64.rpm] action create_if_missing (sun_java::default line 18)
[Tue, 23 Oct 2012 10:34:36 -0500] INFO: Processing package[jdk-1.6-u30-linux-amd64.rpm] action upgrade (sun_java::default line 25)
[Tue, 23 Oct 2012 10:37:15 -0500] INFO: Processing bash[update-alternatives java] action nothing (sun_java::default line 40)
```

The recipe is show below:

```
    urlVersion = "1."+node["sun_java"]["version"].sub(/[u]/, "-u")
    node.default["sun_java"]["rpm_url"] = "http://***/#{urlVersion}/jdk-#{urlVersion}-linux-#{node["sun_java"]["arch"]}.rpm"

    #Check that we are using the .rpm file because of the recent change
    if File.extname(File.basename(node["sun_java"]["rpm_url"]))!=".rpm"
      raise "You must use the jdk*.rpm file to install the Sun JDK. You can get it from the jdk*-rpm.bin file by running the command './jdk*-rpm.bin -x'"
    end

    javaRPM = File.basename(node["sun_java"]["rpm_url"])

    remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{javaRPM}" do
      action :create_if_missing
      source node["sun_java"]["rpm_url"]
      mode "0755"
      backup false
    end

    package javaRPM do
      action :install
      source "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{javaRPM}"
      options "--nogpgcheck" # sun/oracle doesn't sign their RPMs o_O
      notifies :run, "bash[update-alternatives java]", :immediately
    end

    javaHomeFolder = "/usr/java/jdk1.#{node["sun_java"]["version"].sub(/[u]/, ".0_")}"
    jdkFolder = "#{javaHomeFolder}/bin"
    slaveString = ""

    node["sun_java"]["update_slaves"].each do |java_bin|
      slaveString = slaveString + "--slave \"/usr/bin/#{java_bin}\" \"#{java_bin}\" \"#{jdkFolder}/#{java_bin}\" "
    end

    bash "update-alternatives java" do
      action :nothing
      code <<-EOH
        update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "#{jdkFolder}/java" 1 #{slaveString}
        update-alternatives --set java #{jdkFolder}/java
      EOH
    end

    #Remove old environment then notify new environment to be created
    ruby_block "delete_environement" do
            block do
                editBashrc = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/profile")
                    editBashrc.search_file_delete_line(/^.*#JAVA_HOME environment settings.*$/)
                    editBashrc.search_file_delete_line(/^.*#Auto-generated by Chef Cookbook sun_java.*$/)
                    editBashrc.search_file_delete_line(/^.*export JAVA_HOME=.*$/)
                    editBashrc.write_file 
            end
            action :create
    end

    #create environment of root user
    execute "create_environment" do
      user "root"
      command "echo -e '#JAVA_HOME environment settings\n#Auto-generated by Chef Cookbook sun_java\nexport JAVA_HOME=#{javaHomeFolder}' >> /etc/profile"
    end
```

Comment: Can you show the part of your recipe where you call those items?

Comment: @jstim I have added the recipe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this is old, but I believe you want:

```
remote_file "your-remote-file" do
  ...
  not_if "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'your-package'"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with RPM, but you can check out how [chef learns if the package is already installed](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/package/rpm.rb) (the load_current_resource method). You can implement something similar in your recipe and add this condition to remote_file:

```
remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{javaRPM}" do
  not_if { [your_code_that_checks_if_package_installed] }
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Chef provide a resource for [rpm_packages](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_rpm_package.html).
and you can find a lot numbers of examples that show how [chef verify](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html) if a package is installed

Answer (score 1):

You can first remove the package using `ignore_failure` and then install it

```
package 'package_name'
  ignore_failure true
  action         :remove
end
```

Then grab the file

```
remote_file localPath do
    source packageUrl
    mode 0644
    checksum checkSum
end
```

Then install the package

```
package packageName do
      source localPath
      action :install
      allow_downgrade true
end
```

This will work with any package type. For rpm's ideally you do not need to remove the package. `allow_downgrade` should work. But it didn't work for me.

For checksum use `curl packageUrl | shasum -a 256`

Answer (score 1):

There is another way with **not_if**, see an example below

```
execute 'yum -y install ntp' do
  not_if "rpm -qa | grep 'ntp'"
end
```